# how to deploy IWshRuntimeLibrary?

Tags: c#, windows, c#-3.0

I am using .Net 3.5 and C# 3.0, application is creating shortcuts using IWshRuntimeLibrary.

In my understanding IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll is an automatically generated wrapper for wshom.ocx

I am required to support the following Windows Script Host versions:

- Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows XP SP3    - v5.7
- Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2    - v5.8
- Windows 8, Windows Server 2012   - v5.8

Windows Script Host comes with Windows by default.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399806/can-we-deploy-iwshruntimelibrary-with-our-project) is suggesting that I will have to deploy IWshRuntimeLibrary dll with my project.

What would be to correct way of deploying IWshRuntimeLibrary that would allow it work with both versions of Windows Script Host in all required environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a .NET reference to your project for the wshom.ocx file, Visual Studio should generate an interop DLL that you can include in your installer.  This DLL should be in your bin folder when you build the project.

If there's a Primary Interop Assembly available, then Visual Studio should detect that.

This is an older article, but still relevant on the topic: http://www32.brinkster.com/srisamp/netArticles/article_16.htm

Comment: Please correct me if I am wring but that would only work with WSH version that is installed on my dev PC.

Comment: The COM interfaces never change, so as long as you stick to features in the oldest version (5.7) you should be fine.

Comment: So the shortcut functionality that I am using in v5.7 should work exactly the same in v5.8? I am wondering if it would complain that IWshRuntimeLibrary was generated for a different version.  This post suggests that you should check the version: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0c658855-ee41-4260-9c65-ce048765009e/iwshruntimelibrary?forum=clr

Comment: If you generated for 5.8 then you'd have to ensure that you weren't running on a system with only 5.7 installed, but if you generate for the lowest version you shouldn't have a problem